# How to get all (distinct) class name of all child element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list box like this

```
 <div class="selectdiv">
    <select class="mainclass" id="subcat">
    <option>Select Category</option>
<option class="class1" value="val1" >VAL1 </option>                              
<option class="class1" value="val2" >VAL2</option>                              
<option class="class2" value="val3" >VAL3</option>                              
<option class="class2" value="val4" >VAL4</option>                              
<option class="class2" value="val5" >VAL5</option>                                                        
<option class="class3" value="val7" >VAL6</option>                              
<option class="class3" value="val8" >VAL7</option>
</select>                    
</div>
```

I would like to get the class name of all its child element (class1,class2, class3) ... It will be better if I can get all distinct names. So far I have tried the following things

```
$('#subcat').children('option')
$('#subcat option').attr('className')
```

In 1st its giving me list with other parameters along with the class name But it is returning undefined in 2nd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the child element can have multiple classes

```
var obj = {};
$('#subcat').children().each(function () {
    $.each((this.className || '').split(/\s+/), function (i, v) {
        obj[v] = true;
    })
})
var classes = $.map(obj, function (val, key) {
    return key == '' ? undefined : key;
})
console.log(classes)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e8K7V/)

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through elements and put the distinct class names in some array.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sn5Jk/)**

```
var classList = [];
$('#subcat option').each(function () {
    if (this.className != "" && classList.indexOf(this.className) == -1) 
        classList.push(this.className);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you want all the classes in an array then use:

```
var cls = [];
$('#subcat').find('option').each(function(){
    cls.push(this.className);
});
```

this will output you all the class names.

if you want distinct class names like only `class2`: then:

```
var cls = [];
$('#subcat').find('option[class$="2"]').each(function(){
    cls.push(this.className);
});
```

this will output you all the class names which ends with `2`.

or if you want to get all class name except this `class2` then:

```
var cls = [];
$('#subcat').find('option:not([class$="2"])').each(function(){
    cls.push(this.className);
});
```

this will loop through each element except the class name which ends with `2` and pushes all the class names here.